# How can I make DOMParser parse rootless XML without throwing exceptions?

Tags: java, xml, dom, domparser

Imagine I have a rootless XML which looks like this:

```
<LetsGoBrandon></LetsGoBrandon>
<LetsGoBrandon></LetsGoBrandon>
```

I am getting XMLs like this from an external system that **I cannot change**. I need to parse them inside the Camunda BPM platform. Internally it uses `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser`.

When I try to parse the above XML with `DOMParser` in [this test](https://github.com/dptij/rootless-xml/blob/master/src/test/java/XmlParsingTest.java)

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class XmlParsingTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, SAXException {
        final DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
        final String xml = "<LetsGoBrandon></LetsGoBrandon><LetsGoBrandon></LetsGoBrandon>";
        parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
[Fatal Error] :1:33: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 33; The markup 
in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:262)
```

**How can I make sure that `DOMParser` parses the above XML without errors and returns the correct result?**

**Update 1:** Using a SAX parser did not help.

```
    @Test
    public void testSax() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        final SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        final SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML)), new DefaultHandler());
    }
```

Comment: You said you cannot change the xml, but can you wrap it with a dummy element (root)? Or treat each element as a separate xml and parse X xmls?

Comment: @Shadov Thanks. This is an option. But my ideal variant is to set some parameter of `DOMParser`.

Comment: Nope, no such parameter. Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as "rootless XML" - the fragment above is just no XML!

Comment: @Shadov FYI: Here is the preliminary implementation of your suggestion: https://github.com/dptij/camunda-spin/pull/1/files